Импорт выдаёт ошибку, что не нашёл мой модуль
у меня есть некий ког для основного кода бота, в котором есть команда бан, для того чтобы бан был лишь на время я создал файл str_time_to_seconds.py, в которой есть функция str_time_to_seconds, и при импорте import str_time_to_seconds выдаёт ошибку:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Python\Python310\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\common_bot_base.py", line 452, in _load_from_module_spec
    spec.loader.exec_module(lib)  # type: ignore
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "discord_bot-main\cogs\mod.py", line 3, in <module>
    import str_time_to_seconds
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'str_time_to_seconds'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "discord_bot-main\bot.py", line 21, in <module>
    bot.load_extension("cogs." + filename[:-3])
  File "Python\Python310\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\common_bot_base.py", line 523, in load_extension
    self._load_from_module_spec(spec, name)
  File "Python\Python310\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\common_bot_base.py", line 455, in _load_from_module_spec
    raise errors.ExtensionFailed(key, e) from e
disnake.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.mod' raised an error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'str_time_to_seconds'


Так нельзя выполнять импорт. Ознакомьтесь с правилами импортирования функций из файлов, расписанными в любом самоучителе по Питону. Проблема в этом: "...str_time_to_seconds.py, в которой есть функция str_time_to_seconds...". Несчастный Питон не может понять что и куда ему импортировать.
